# Wordpress - display pages that made path to the current page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with Wordpress. My goal is to display dynamical path to the current page - something like this: **Home / Blog / Post - Name**. It's inside blog page so it can't be done using static html since it's dynamically changing (or maybe with help of ACF?).

All i found was next/previous links and tutorials how to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like you are trying to have breadcrumbs to your site. Either you can install a plugin like Yoast SEO or other to have breadcrumb. In case, if you want to code it yourself, you can take a look at https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/wordpress-creating-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin

Comment: Yes! I knew that it was mentioned somewhere, but didn't know how to name it. It's funny. because I've been wondering lately what bredcrumbs are. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

We’ve created a custom function called get_breadcrumb() to generate the breadcrumb links. You only need to add the get_breadcrumb() function code in functions.php file of the current theme.

```
function get_breadcrumb() {
    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'" rel="nofollow">Home</a>';
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        the_category(' &bull; ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo " &nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
                the_title();
            }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo the_title();
    } elseif (is_search()) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Results for... ";
        echo '"<em>';
        echo the_search_query();
        echo '</em>"';
    }
}
```

Display Breadcrumbs:
Call the get_breadcrumb() function in single.php file and others files where you want to display the breadcrumbs on your WordPress site.

```
<div class="breadcrumb"><?php get_breadcrumb(); ?></div>
```

https://www.codexworld.com/wordpress-how-to-display-breadcrumb-without-plugin/